# Creating application specific hotkeys in OS X

Tags: windows, macos, hotkeys

In Windows there is a program that sits in the tray and allows you to define application specific hotkeys for any program.  Is there a similar program for OS X?

There is a certain program where I want to map w as the up directional key, s as the down directional key, a as the left directional key, and d as the right directional key. The application does not have this type of key mapping functionality built-in. How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know about keyboard shortcuts, you can perform any menu action from System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts.

However, to **remap** keys on the keyboard you might check out one of the following apps:

- [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) (actually works on all Macs, not just Macbooks...)
- [fKeys](http://www.kodachi.com/software/fKeys/about.html) (claims to work only in OS 10.4/Tiger)

Comment: And Ukelele! http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele

Answer (score 1):

[Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2490#l4) describing system method to set application-specific keyboard shortcuts.

If you're looking for a way to map no-modifier hotkeys in a specific application, don't remap keys, [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) should do the trick.